# How to handle accessibility in custom view when it is not designed for handling clicks?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've written a chessboard component in android, by subclassing view. It only process drag and drop from user. But Android Studio complains about the fact that performClick is not handled for this view, so that accessibility is not handled correctly.

But as I manage Dnd and not a simple click, how to resolve this problem ?
In fact, I am just overriding onTouchEvent, managing ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP. But I can't see how to adapt the code for onPerformClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here:

1, Add suppress lint warning annotation for `onTouchEvent`

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```

2, override performClick:

```
override fun performClick(): Boolean {
    return super.performClick()
}
```

Your choice ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I think the suppress warning is the best option for me, as the feature is not adapted for me.